# How can I add a wmode="opaque" or wmode="transparent" to this php snippet for youtube?

Tags: php, youtube

**NOTE TO THE ABOVE COMMENT: This is NOT a duplicate question!**

> The above didn't resolve my issue; I already know about the opaque and
>   transparent attributes ... my issue is assimilating them into the php
>   code given.

I have a youtube video page that's overlapping my top navigational video.  I've read that including the attribute **wmode="opaque"** will solve the issue.

But I'm unsure as to how to implement it within PHP.

The code that calls the video is:

```
  if ($showcase != ""):

    if (isset($_GET['entry'])) { 
        $iframe_src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $_GET['entry'] . '?version=3&
f=videos&app=youtube_gdata&autoplay=1';
    }
    else {
        $iframe_src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $showcase . '?version=3&
f=videos&app=youtube_gdata&autoplay=1';
    }

    $showcase_output = "<iframe height='" . $showcase_height . "' width='". 
$showcase_width . "' src='" . $iframe_src . "'></iframe>";

  endif;
```

Does anybody know how I can make these videos **opaque**, dynamically in php, so my top navigational menu overlaps the videos, instead of the other way around?  I've searched for answers in the forums, but haven't figured out a solution yet.  Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer!

Comment: Also, you can clean up that string concatenation: `$showcase_output = "<iframe height='$showcase_height' width='$showcase_width' src='$iframe_src'></iframe>";`

Comment: Hi Matt.  I thought I looked at all the questions (that showed up in the right-hand column).  I cleaned up that string, per your suggestion, and am now just trying to implement one of these solutions.  Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: I did look at that link, however, and none of those solutions worked ... I mean, I realize the wmode transparent/opaque attributes.  My issues is with assimilating them properly into the php.

Answer (score 2):

```
$iframe_src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $showcase . '?wmode=opaque&version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata&autoplay=1';
```

should work.

Comment: hi User ... thank you for taking the time to respond!  I tried this solution, but that didn't appear to solve anything, although you think it would ... I had originally put the &mode=opaque at the end, but putting it in the beginning didn't work either.  Quite confounding!  Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$iframe_src .= (empty($iframe_src) ? '?' : '&').'wmode=opaque';
```

Comment: Hi Phillippe.  Being a php newbie (asp.net convert), are you suggesting I replace one of my lines, or add that line to the code?  Thanks for taking the time to offer the solution!

Comment: add this line after your `if(){}` before `$showcase_output`